# Como "ligar" um domínio já comprado a um Site na Amazon Ec2?

Tags: dns, domínio, amazon-aws

Possuo um site que está alojado na HostTugaTech, e nesse mesmo site comprei o domínio para o meu site.

No entanto, devido a problemas, fiz a transição do meu site para a amazon ec2. 
Agora, preciso de fazer a ligação do site ao meu dominio que comprei. Após contactar a HostTugaTech, verifiquei que necessito de 1 nameservers funcionais para tudo funcionar.
Apesar de já ter criado 2 elastic IP's na amazon, quando vou verificar se o dns está funcional ([aqui](https://www.dns.pt/technical-reviewer)) dá-me erro.

Alguém já fez algo parecido e me pode dar uma ajuda como fazer esta parte?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o `Route 53` da AWS, inserindo os nameservers fornecidos por este serviço lá na configuração do seu domínio.
Depois, na configuração do DNS dentro do Route 53, aponte os serviços que quer para seu `Elastic IP`.
Como sugestão adicional, tente assumir o controle de seu domínio eliminando intermediários, ou seja, administrar seu domínio a partir do painel de controle da empresa que forneceu o registro (Godaddy, Registar, etc)