# Configurar domínio na Amazon com Route 53

Tags: domínio, amazon-aws

Comecei a usar o AWS recentemente na versão free e comprei um domínio na Go Daddy, depois que subi a minha instância tentei configurar o domínio com esse [tutorial](http://www.wbotelhos.com/configurando-dominio-na-amazon-route-53-e-godaddy)

Basicamente aloquei um IP com o Elastic IP e configurei no Route 53 como descrito no tutorial. 
Na primeira vez, quando acessava eu era redirecionada pela página padrão da Go Daddy (aquela página padrão "Você registrou o seu domínio.
Agora, coloque-o para trabalhar.")  e outras vezes para a página correta da minha instância, só que isso persistiu mesmo após cerca de 30 minutos de eu ter configurado, nem todos os servidores me redirecionavam para o endereço correto.
Ontem desaloquei o IP, aloquei outro e repeti o tutorial, aguardei para testar hoje cedo mas dessa vez já caia direto para a página padrão da Go Daddy (eu troquei as configurações do domínio na Go Daddy)

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: Acho que esse video pode te ajudar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIXomzvf-Zk

Comment: Veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23050/como-ligar-um-dom%C3%ADnio-j%C3%A1-comprado-a-um-site-na-amazon-ec2/23055#23055

Comment: DNS demora para difundir, até 24h. Não poderia ser isto? (Assumindo que realmente funciona numa parte das vezes.)

Comment: @epx Sim, realmente foi isso e acabei atrasando mais ainda o processo nas tentativas de reconfigurar. Acho que o prazo é até de 48h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O tutorial usado está corrento, os passos são esses mesmos:

1. Solicitar o IP;
2. Gerar a lista de servidores DNS para o IP, 2 servidores é bom, 4 são ótimo;
3. Inserir as informações de DNS no host;

Após isso use ferramentas como [What is my DNS](https://www.whatsmydns.net) para verificar a propagação do DNS e o [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) para verificar se o seu computador consegue atingir o servidor.

Nos últimos casos que tive problema de propagação de DNS foram causados pelo meu provedor de acesso, mesmo com o What is my DNS me indicando a propagação em todos os locais do mundo. Solucionei isso trocando em meu router o DNS padrão da operadora pelo da [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/), pode usar o do Google também.